# traitCollectionDidChange not called when multitasking

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, multitasking

I'm working on an adopting multitasking to support split view for app, but I find the `traitCollectionDidChange` not called when app is on the right.

Does anyone have idea about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried the viewWillTransitionToSize method? This is used to notify the container that the size of its view is about to change.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

**Swift**

```
func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("landscape")
    } else {
        print("portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i have tried. That's working.  But I want to get notification when change is end. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Have you added this check in there UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue, this will give you the current orientation state. I have updated the code with an example.

Comment: No, i didn't check that

Comment: viewWillTransitionToSize is called in situations other than trait change (like rotation on compact iPhones), hence not a good choice here.

Answer (score 14):

You may override `traitCollectionDidChange` in your `ViewController`.

**However.**

`traitCollectionDidChange` called when you change from one split view mode to another. For example from 50/50 view to 33/66. It so **NOT** called when you enter multitasking mode or exit it.

If you need to handle **all events** including entering and exiting multitasking mode, use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` instead:

```
// put this in your ViewController code     
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
        [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
        // TODO: put your code here (runs BEFORE transition complete)
    }
```

If you want your code called **AFTER** the transition compelete:

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        // TODO: put your code here (runs AFTER transition complete)
    }];
}
```

Comment: Just a hint for whoever read this. `traitCollectionDidChange` isn't always called when you change split mode like you said "from 50/50 view to 33/66". It will be only called, if actual size class is changed. E.g. if you have an iPad, not iPad pro, and your app is appear from right, traitCollectionDidChange will not be called, because a size class in both modes will be Compact.

Comment: Thank you for this comment! Only Apple can make a simplest thing (handling view size change in this case) so complicated and unclear!

Comment: traitCollectionDidChange working fine for me for iPad multitasking.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone still doubt that is the point:

```
// This method called every time user changes separator position or when user rotates device 
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    // Always call super in those methods
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    // Before this call your layout is old, status bar orientation will return value before rotation

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
       // Code here will be executed during transform. Status bar orientation is new, your view size already changed (in general).
       // Setup required animations or custom views transitions
    }
    completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        // Split view transition complete or device rotated
    }];
}
```

Also there is a method `traitCollectionDidChange:`, but it will be called only when horizontal size class actually changed. For example, if your app presenting from right side in split view mode, `traitCollectionDidChange:` will not be called when user changed separator position. But if your app presenting from left, it will be called always in portrait mode, and in landscape for transitions `(50/50) <-> (66/33)`

Answer (score 1):

In view controller, we should call

`- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {`

to get notified when the orientation/multi window view changes.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation of [UITraitEnvironment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITraitEnvironment/traitCollectionDidChange:):

The system calls this method when the iOS interface environment changes. Implement this method in view controllers and views, according to your app’s needs, to respond to such changes. For example, you might adjust the layout of the subviews of a view controller when an iPhone is rotated from portrait to landscape orientation. The default implementation of this method is empty.
At the beginning of your implementation, call super to ensure that interface elements higher in the view hierarchy have an opportunity to adjust their layout first.